# Disable context menu items in Adobe PDF when in embedded mode

Tags: javascript, pdf, menu, dom-events, adobe

I am trying to disable certain elements in the right context menu on PDF object embedded in an HTML page. The PDF is rendered with Adobe Acrobat 11. I've tried the following solutions but neither work especially in embedded browser mode:

http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/2009/11/11/adobe-reader-how-to-disable-toolbar-buttons-and-menu-items/

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4288436?tstart=0

Any ideas what else  I could try?